# How should the three generic types of this generic interface (SessionCallback) be written? Why does IDEA give an error prompt?

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

The interface is SessionCallback in Spring-data-redis (version 3.2.3), defined as follows:

```
public interface SessionCallback<T> {
    @Nullable
    <K, V> T execute(RedisOperations<K, V> operations) throws DataAccessException;
}
```

When I was using it, I tried to implement it as follows:

```
public class CustomSessionCallback implements SessionCallback<String> {
    @Override
    public String execute(RedisOperations<String, String> operations) throws DataAccessException {
        operations.opsForValue().set("key", "value");
        return operations.opsForValue().get("key");
    }
}
```

But IDEA prompts that I haven't overridden the method of the parent class. Why is that?